# PHP Split array values based on time

Tags: php

I want this human readable words into php code:

Take all values from column "Ratings" WHERE Time >= 24 hours
    Split them into 1 hour each
       Take average Rating values for each hour and put them into 24 variables

WhatI'm doing now is a bad long code :/

I'm taking them an hour after another, each one in a separate function where I specify an hour via mysql select statement!

I'm new in programming, and I couldn't figure out what to do to get all values at once, and split them into 1 hour each

Thanks

Comment: please rephrase: I have a db, this is its structure, here is a few lines, i want to query it and output XXX

Comment: Can you give us a little more information about your setup? What does the table look like (you can use a `SHOW CREATE table foo` query, where 'foo' is the name of your table)? What is your expected output (mock it up with notepad or something).

Comment: yeah we need some more info. could you post your database table here and its data, your code, and what you expected to get.

Comment: Sorry guys. Here you go:

Database name: db
1 Table called: info
2 columns: Rating (numbers from 1 to 5) | Time (unix time stamp)

I hope this is helpful. I'm new on this, and still learning the basics, so bare with me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: changed the fiddle, so it uses time as an int, that represents seconds since January 1st, 1970.

Take a look at this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e6b6/5/0
It is returning the rating average on a hourly basis. Is this that you need? I think you might tune the query for your other needs.

You can read more about it at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Thanks Alexand, this tool looks really helpful. But the Time data saved in my database are in unix formar. How do I alert the fiddle tool to save it in this format too?

Comment: I think you should change the data type I used for the column. For unix time you milliseconds since January 1st, 1970 right? Can you print the create table script you are using, plz?

Comment: I think it won't work Alexander, because time is saved as unix time, which means as (int). How can we slice integers into hours in mySQL SELECT statment?

Comment: Do you mean you are saving a rank entry for right now like 20130702093500 (which means year month day hour minute second, all concatenated) or like 1372768688 (seconds since January 1st 1970) ?

Comment: that will do the trick: select date_format(from_unixtime(date), '%H') as hour, avg(rank) from ratings group by hour;

Comment: Great Alexander, it's working now. But how can I put the results now into 24 variables, one for each hour, so that I can use them whenever I want

Comment: The other question is: Can I modify the range to, seconds, minutes, days, months, only by changing %H to %S, %M, %D .. ?

Answer (score 0):

Got it, after so many searches. Learning is beautiful :)

This is the code

```
$mysql = "select date_format(from_unixtime(Time), '%H') as hour, avg(Rate) from za7ma1 group by hour";

$result = mysql_query($mysql) or die(mysql_error());

            // Print out result
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "The average for this hour ". $row['hour']. " is ".$row['avg(Rate)'];
        echo "<br />";
    }
```

Thanks to Alexander Jardim for the great tool http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e6b6/5/0 which opened my eyes on avg() mysql function

Comment: @Mohammmad, plz, don't use mysql_* functions. You should use PDO for better compliance with php modern standards. Take a lookt at http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php